# Cast-expression semantic in C

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, language-lawyer, precision

I was confused by the following wording in the Standard 6.5.4/6:

> If the value of the expression is represented with greater range or
>   precision than required by the type named by the cast (6.3.1.8), then
>   the cast specifies a conversion even if the type of the expression is
>   the same as the named type and removes any extra range and precision.

The thing that I cannot understand is if the named type and the type of the expression  is the same how can the value of the expression have some extra range or precision.

Can you provide an example demonstrating the rule? For now it looks a bit confusing.

Comment: Have a look at the classic paper[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), search for "Subexpression evaluation is imprecisely defined in many languages", and read the next few paragraphs.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz can you copy the relevant sections and post it as an answer rather than just putting a link? Not everyone can/might want to follow a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard permits floating-point to be computed in higher accuracy than the type of the expression; for example:

```
float f = 1.234f * 5.678f;
```

The compiler is allowed to convert the operands to `long double`, do the multiplication, and then convert back to `float`.  The rationale for this is that on many processors it's faster to just use a particular floating point register size for computations and usually people don't care about gaining precision.

This is specified in C17 5.2.4.2.2/9:

> Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision), the values yielded by operators with floating operands and values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of floating constants are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be greater than required by the type. The use of evaluation formats is characterized by the implementation-defined value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`:
>
> - `−1` indeterminable;
> - `0` evaluate all operations and constants just to the range and precision of the type;
> - `1` evaluate operations and constants of type float and double to the range and precision of the double type, evaluate long double operations and constants to the range and precision of the long double type;
> - `2` evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of the long double type.
>
> All other negative values for `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` characterize implementation-defined behavior.

So you can inspect `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to find out whether the compiler might do this, but you can't necessarily control the setting yourself.

---

The text you quote is reaffirming that the cast operator converts the result back to the type of the cast, e.g.:

```
float f = 1.234f * 5.678f + 9.012f;
```

could theoretically give a more accurate result than:

```
float f = (float)(1.234f * 5.678f) + 9.012f;
```

Comment: I suspect it could give a less accurate result too, for some other choices of numbers. As the answer states, what is actually allowed is to compute with more precision. And there could be perverse cases where the rounding with `float` results in a more accurate answer than rounding with more precision. I would have to think about it for a bit, though—just speculation until then.